# question about a notation in Atiyah's book K-Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

[image]

Here is a copy of a theorem from Atiyah's book on page 29. My queation is that what is the meaning of the following notation? Or what is the exact definition of this set?
[image]

I did not find the explanaton of this notation before this page. Thanks!

Comment: Direct limit of the spaces of homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to the Grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^m$.